# Data-driven Testing with Jest

Tags: mysql, selenium, automated-tests, jestjs, data-driven-tests

Need to automate tests with the values retrieve from the database. Also, the same test is needed to be run with a set of data.

I use the Jest Testing framework and have to use it.test() to test the data. The issue is the test file first checks the array that I am passing to it.test() and initially, it is empty. Please check the attached code.

```
import "jest";

describe('Document Training test suit', function(this:any){

let docTrainingPage: DocumentTraining;   
let driver: any;    
let valuesArray:Array<any>=[];    
var i=0;

beforeAll(async()=>{       
    const driver = await new ConfigBrowser();
    this.driver = driver;
    docTrainingPage = new DocumentTraining(this.driver);
    await docTrainingPage.connectToDB();      

    valuesArray = await docTrainingPage.retrieveValues();//Retrieve value from database
});   


describe('Should not save the document',  async() => { 

    it.each(valuesArray )('Should NOT savedocuments with INVALID values',async() => {       
        const A= JSON.stringify(valuesArray[i].AAA);
        const B= JSON.stringify(valuesArray[i].BBB);
        const C= JSON.stringify(valuesArray[i].CCC);
        const D= JSON.stringify(valuesArray[i].DDD);
        const E= JSON.stringify(valuesArray[i].EEE);           

        await docTrainingPage.enterValues(A, B, C, D, E);

        const testResult = await docTrainingPage.verifyValidDocTrainingSuccessful();
        expect(testResult).toBeTruthy();

        i++;
    });        
})   

afterAll(()=>{
    docTrainingPage.endConnection();
    setTimeout(() => process.exit(), 1000)       
});

})
```

I tried debugging this code. It goes to **beforeAll** first at the beginning. But then its go to **it** and check whether any valid tests are there. At this point, the array is not loaded.

Error

● Test suite failed to run

```
Your test suite must contain at least one test.
```

[image]

Comment: As the database data can change over time, it is best to structure your code so the data access is separate from data validation. That way, you can test the validation against static data to see what happens as specific data is returned.  Then you can mock the database access to return specific data as needed to test your code against the database return.

Comment: How did you solved this?

Comment: Yes already sorted. Thank you :)